# How to send each foreach iteration through to a json payload in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, woocommerce, foreach

So I'm trying to send data to a webhook endpoint. I can't seem to get all the elements in the foreach loop into the json file. In my example below product_name is only showing the last iteration of the loop.

How would I include all the iterations within the $body being sent via wp_remote_post?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){  
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->get_user();
    $order_data = $order->get_data();
    $order_id = $order_data['id'];
    $order_shipping_first_name = $order_data['shipping']['first_name'];
    //$products = wc_order_item_product( $order_id );
    $products = $order->get_items();
    $customer_id = $order->get_shipping_first_name();
    $testTotal = $order_data['shipping']['total'];




    // Iterating through each "line" items in the order
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

        // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
        $product = $item_data->get_product();
        $product_name = $product->get_name(); // Get the product name

        $item_quantity = $item_data->get_quantity(); // Get the item quantity

        $item_total = $item_data->get_total(); // Get the item line total

        // Displaying this data (to check)
        //echo 'Product name: '.$product_name.' | Quantity: '.$item_quantity.' | Item total: '. number_format( $item_total, 2 );
    }


    $url = 'https://example.com'; // post to the request somehow
    //$url = 'https://example.com/; // post to the request somehow

    $body = [
        'order_shipping_first_name' => $order_shipping_first_name,
        'order_shipping_last_name' => $order_data['shipping']['last_name'],
        'order_shipping_company_name' => $order_data['shipping']['company'],
        'order_shipping_address1' => $order_data['shipping']['address_1'],
        'order_shipping_address2' => $order_data['shipping']['address_2'],
        'order_shipping_city' => $order_data['shipping']['city'],
        'order_shipping_state' => $order_data['shipping']['state'],
        'order_shipping_postcode' => $order_data['shipping']['postcode'],
        'order_address'         => $order_address = $order->get_address(),
        'order_note'            => $order_note = $order->get_customer_note(),

        'product_name' => $product_name


        /**'order_items' => $order_items,
        'order_items1' => $item_data,
        'order_items2' => $item_id,
        **/
    ];


    wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
        //'body' => array( 'order' => $order, 'user' => $user, 'order_data' => $order_data, 'order_id' => $order_id, 'order_shipping_first_name' => $order_shipping_first_name),
        'body' => json_encode($body),
        'method'      => 'POST', //added ****
        'cookies' => array()
        )
    );

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm really not a coder, but dipping my toes into the water, so to speak.

Comment: put the product names in an array and then send the array in the request body (assuming the endpoint actually accepts that).

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I think the main thing, and maybe I should clarify. What is getting me is getting all the iterations in the foreach statement, into the body variable, for sending off.

Comment: I know. My suggestion solves that. You need to put all the product names into an array. Each time the foreach runs, add the new product name from that iteration of the loop, into an array (which you created before the loop started). That way you'll end up with a list of product names to put in the body. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ADyson, yes it does make sense now.....
Thanks for your feedback - much appreciated. I've in fact done that now, and my code is working :D - thanks once again. The internet/forums like this is awesome because of people like you willing to help others.